# How to stuff and coat a shark with licorice for biting?

Tags: modeling

I need my shark stuffed and coated with licorice in order to almost bite off it's head:
[image: sketch]

How do I stuff it pink and coat it with an irregular black coat, like this?

[image: licorice]

For the final bitemarks I intend to subtract these teeth:
[image: teeth]

I've coloured the model and subtracted a thin cylinder to get a feeling where I'm directing to:
[image: model]

Answer (score 1):

1. Model your shark
2. Duplicate your model with Ctrl+D to make the inner portion
3. Go to sculpting tab, use the tools to deflate and change the inner portion (turn off symmetry)
4. Go to Addons -> Search for Bool tool -> Activate Bool Tool
5. Make your "teeth" object
   5.5 Duplicate your teeth object
6. Select the teeth object, intersect it with your shark
7. Select the Teeth object first then the shark, and choose Booltool -> Slice
8. Select the cut out portion and delete it
9. Repeat the same with the inner portion
10. Scale the inner portion a tiny bit to prevent z-fighting
11. Apply different materials to the inner portion and the shark
12. Done
    [image]

Comment: @412p9wej, does this answer your question?

Comment: Full of grate for your thoughtful instructions, I'm currently stuck deleting the slice https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213438/how-can-i-slice-with-the-bool-tool-without-leaving-any-remnants