# How can I slice with the bool tool without leaving any remnants?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

1. Select teeth
2. Select fish
3. Slice
   [image: picture]

Delete the slice
[image: picture!]

Result:
[image: picture!]

Moving the teeths before applying the slice tool alters the remaining teeths without leaving any clues why

Teeth object:
[image: picture]

Face orientation:
[image: picture]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference boolean doesn't seem to work on a specific area](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212552/the-difference-boolean-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-a-specific-area)

Comment: @ReinisMazeiks Unfortunately no